# Spiting 2D Arrays using "vbnewline" Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a hard-coded 2d array that prints to a text box in visual basic. However I am unable to split the lines between each row. This is an extract from the array:

```
    stpeople(0, 0) = "Bob"
    stpeople(1, 0) = "Last"

    stpeople(0, 2) = "Jamie"
    stpeople(1, 2) = "Smart"
```

This will show as one line like so:  "Bob Last Jamie Smart"

this is the code that I am using to display the array am I using vbNewLine incorrectly? I am using visual basic.net.

```
    Dim stoutput As String

    For y As Integer = 0 To 9
        For x As Integer = 0 To 4
            stoutput = stoutput & stpeople(x, y) & " "
        Next
        stoutput = stoutput & vbNewLine
    Next
    ListArray.Items.Add(stoutput)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be adding the line break in the inner loop or you'll be putting every element on its own line.  The inner loop should put all elements in a "row" on one line, THEN you add the line break, i.e. in the outer loop after the inner loop.

Comment: As I often say, this is what happens when you try to write code without knowing what it has to do first.  If you had written down your algorithm then you never would have specified to add a line break after every element, so writing code to implement that algorithm would never include such code. Always check your code against your algorithm, so you need an algorithm to check it against.

Comment: I added 'stoutput = stoutput & vbNewLine' after the first next statement and removed the vbNewLine is that what you mean? also changed the 0 to 9 to 0 to 0 and copied for each row. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Does it matter if I print to a textbox or a popup box? @jmcilhinney

Comment: What I mean is what I said. Make an attempt to do what I said, test it and, if it doesn't work, update your question with the new code and an explanation of what happens when you run it.  That said, how can a loop from 0 to 0 make sense?  I said to change where the line break was added.  I'm not sure what about that made you think that you should change the loop limits.

Comment: @jmcilhinney right dont get upset because I dont understand I have tried moving outside that 0 to 4 loop  and it still didn't work instead of coming back to you and just saying it didn't work I attempted to trouble shoot it myself, I have changed the code in the question to I assume what you mean but if i'm incorrect let me know. created 0 to 0 to see if it would create a new line for a new loop but that did not work either still printed it out inside the text box in one line.

Comment: You did set the `Multiline` property of the `TextBox` to `True`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type is ListArray but I'll try to guess. Sometime, these things don't display new lines, you would need to add each line to the Items.

```
Dim stoutput As String

For y As Integer = 0 To 9
    stoutput = ""

    For x As Integer = 0 To 4
        stoutput = stoutput & stpeople(x, y) & " "
    Next

    ListArray.Items.Add(stoutput)
Next
```

Your code should work with textbox, if not, it mean you didn't set them to [support multiline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.multiline?view=netframework-4.7.2).